# Horizontal line in R plotly, when xaxis is discrete

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I would like to create a `bar plot` (with the `plotly` package), which (for some months) would have `red horizontal line` (gain to obtain). Plots below show my problem more precisely, I hope.

[image]

Code and data needed to obtain first plot:

```
library("plotly")
library("dplyr")

data.frame(miesiac_label = as.character(as.roman(c(1:12))),
           miesiac = c(1:12),
           ile = c(12000, 12100, 11100, 12000, 12000, 11900, 12200, 12100, 6000, 12100, 12100, 12100),
           gain = c(rep(NA, 7), 11000, 12000, 12000, 12000, 12000)) -> dane
dane$miesiac_label <- factor(dane$miesiac_label, levels = dane[["miesiac_label"]])

plot_ly(dane) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~miesiac_label, y = ~ile,
              type = 'bar', marker = list(color = '#99d3df')) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~miesiac_label, y = ~gain, name = 'Gain', 
              type = "scatter", mode='lines+markers', marker = list(color = 'red'),
              line = list(color = 'red'))
```

I think that I should have a continuous scale to do this and after this just change `x axis labels`, but I don't know how to change those labels (I've tried to find it in google first, of course)...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Your code gives an empty plot for me, are you sure it's correct?

Comment: @MarijnStevering, yes, I've just checked it once again for you - it's correct.

Comment: Ah, updating my plotly fixed it, my bad.

Comment: without running the code, your problem looks to me likee something that could be handled with `group` in ggplot2... I don't know what's the plotly equivalent, but perhaps that's worth a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like that work for you. You could adjust the numbers in `add_segments`.

```
 a <- list(
  title = "miesiac_label",
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  tickmode= "array",
  ticktext = as.character(as.roman(c(1:12))),
 tickvals = c(1:12)
)

 plot_ly(dane) %>%
    add_bars(x = ~miesiac, y = ~ile) %>%
    add_segments(x = 7.5, xend = 8.5, y = 10000, yend = ~10000, line = list(dash = "dash")) %>%
    add_segments(x = 8.5, xend = 12.5, y = 12000, yend = ~12000, line = list(dash = "dash")) %>% 
    layout(showlegend = FALSE, xaxis =  a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to construct what you want using `ggplot` and the fantastic `ggplotly()`

Doing it normally for ggplot standards leads to hideous tooltips on hover, but that can be tweaked with the `text` aesthetic and the `tooltip` argument in the `ggplotly` call

for example:

```
ggplot(dane, aes(x = miesiac_label, y = ile)) +
  geom_bar(aes(text = paste("x:", miesiac_label, "y:",ile)),
                            stat = "identity", fill = "#99d3df") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = miesiac - 0.5, xend = miesiac + 0.5, 
                   y = gain, yend = gain, 
                   text = paste0("gain: ",gain))
               , colour = "red"
               , linetype = 2)

ggplotly(tooltip = "text")
```

Which results in the following plot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but actually I know how to do it with `ggplot2` :) And I had some reasons not to use `ggplotly()`. Although, I don't really remember them :) I'm looking for some `plotly`'s solution.

Comment: Ah, well then I'm no help, since all of my `plotly` experience is through `ggplotly`